# .mat file not opening up

Tags: r, matlab

So, I have dataset in file which has `.mat` shortcut. When, I try to open the file using matlab, it shows the error,

`??? Undefined function or method 'uiimport' for input arguments of type 'char'.`u

How should I open this file? Can I open the file in someway using R? Or Excel?

The file is of 160 MB and contains the following information.

```
Specifications:

author_name: the namer of each author
paper_name: the title of each paper
venue_name: the name of each conference/journal (here, we did not distinguish conference and journal)

num_author, num_paper, num_venue: the total number of different authors, papers, and venues.

paper_year: An array to represent the year of publication.
paper_venue: An array to show the venue of publication (Note that some papers does not have venue information, we set it the venue value to -1)

paper_author: A sparse matrix to represent the paper-author relationship (Note that some papers does not have any authors)

citation: A sparse matrix to represent the citation network (Extremely sparse)
```

Comment: I did. That is only for viewing the variables in the file, I want to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file may of been created using a class definition of some sort.  Meaning your mat file may have an object saved to it for which there is no class definition on path.  I would contact the author of the file and ask if there are any class definitions for which the data depends on.

It may help to supply us with an example of how your trying to open the file and the full error message if you haven't already supplied it.

Comment: I downloaded the dataset off the internet.

Comment: How are you opening the file?

Comment: I am opening my matlab. And then from `file->import data`.

Comment: try, `open('filename.mat')`.  You may need to navigate your 'Current Folder' to the correct directory.

Comment: It shows the error: `??? Undefined function or method 'open' for input arguments of type 'char'.`

Comment: Can you open any other mat files?